# Combine one condition can we update increment and decrement mongodb base on condition?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Can we update increment and decrement mongodb base on condition?

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("60e80c96b9c55e7a01898f5c"),
  "watched.3": {
    $exists: true
  }
},
{
  $inc: {
    fans: 1
  }
})
```

```
if watched.3 exists then 
  remove 3 and fans = -1
else 
  add watched.3 and fans +2
```

Please guide

https://mongoplayground.net/p/h1xioEpZ99Z

Comment: db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "watched.3",
              true
            ]
          },
          {
            $inc: 2
          },
          {
            $inc: -3
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Comment: tried but getting query failed: (InvalidPipelineOperator) Invalid $project :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$inc'